# actual dimensions of background image with "zoom" layout

Tags: c#, winforms

With "Zoom" layout background image actual width and height do not always match the width and height of the containing control, as opposed to "Stretch" layout. I am wondering if there is a property or something in winforms to retrieve current image rendered dimensions without doing any math?

Comment: Nothing that I know of.  Is the math really that intimidating?

Comment: @adv12 no, I love math, in fact I already did it while waiting for the anwser, but why reinvent a wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns the `Rectangle` pixels from a `PictureBox` for any of its `SizeModes`.

But yes, it does take some math for Zoom mode.

It can be adapted easily to the corresponding `BackgroudImageLayout` values:

```
Rectangle ImageArea(PictureBox pbox)
{
    Size si = pbox.Image.Size;
    Size sp = pbox.ClientSize;

    if (pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage) return pbox.ClientRectangle;
    if (pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal ||
       pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize) return new Rectangle(Point.Empty, si);
    if (pbox.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage)
        return new Rectangle(new Point( (sp.Width - si.Width) / 2,
                            (sp.Height - si.Height) / 2), si); 

    //  PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    float ri = 1f * si.Width / si.Height;
    float rp = 1f * sp.Width / sp.Height;
    if (rp > ri)
    {
        int width = si.Width * sp.Height / si.Height;
        int left = (sp.Width - width) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(left, 0, width, sp.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        int height = si.Height * sp.Width / si.Width;
        int top = (sp.Height - height) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(0, top, sp.Width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kinda looks like what I have come up with, though there is not a single word in the question about `PictureBox`

Comment: True but the `BackgroundImageLayout` for Controls like `Panel` or `Label` are basically the same as the `PictureBoxSizeMode`, except that it has no `Tile` mode but has an `Autosize` mode.

Comment: What's with the edit two years later (multiplying by 1)?